# Differentiate $g\circ f$ transformation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, function-and-relation-composition

Differentiate $g \circ f$ of the following functions:

$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $$

$$f(x,y)=(x-y,x+y)$$
$$g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $$
$$g(x_1,x_2)=(e^{x_1} \cos x_2,e^{x_1}\sin x_2)$$
I am looking for the solution that would involve use of jacobian matrix.

Comment: the differential of that function is the product of the jacobian of single application $g$ and $f$. You have to use the chain rule

Comment: I would appreciate further explanation.

Comment: will it be jacobian matrix of $g(f(x))$ times the jacobian matrix of $f(x)$

Comment: yes that's right